# Xamarin + RestSharp + .Net Core Web API - Value cannot be null.Parameter name: src

Tags: azure, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, restsharp

I have a WebAPI in .NET Core 2.1 e I have using the RestSharp to access the API. When I send a request (POST), I always receive the below message in the response:

---

{System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadAsync): ReceiveFailure Value cannot be null.Parameter name: src ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: src  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000ba] in <b78695579ed9422b8bc80218eeda782c>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0   at System.Net.WebResponseStream+d__48.MoveNext () [0x00253] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00077] in :0   at RestSharp.Extensions.MiscExtensions.ReadAsBytes (System.IO.Stream input) [0x0001f] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0   at RestSharp.Http.ProcessResponseStream (System.IO.Stream webResponseStream, RestSharp.HttpResponse response) [0x0000e] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0   at RestSharp.Http.ExtractResponseData (RestSharp.HttpResponse response, System.Net.HttpWebResponse webResponse) [0x0004c] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0   at RestSharp.Http+<>c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0 (System.Net.HttpWebResponse webResponse) [0x00001] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0   at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponseAsync (System.IAsyncResult result, System.Action`1[T] callback) [0x00050] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0   at RestSharp.Http.ResponseCallback (System.IAsyncResult result, System.Action`1[T] callback) [0x0005a] in <4b0c1fc6e5a94482990701acc6dec8b3>:0 }

---

The previous version of my service (.NET Framework 4.7) was working, but my new version is not. I checked the URL and that is okay, and the service is working on Swagger and Postman, and I have the SSL certificate configured on the server, but in the App I continue receiving such message.

My service is hosted on Microsoft Azure.

Does anyone any idea to help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I resolved.

I had the below code:

```
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(method, Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("SampleKey", "SampleValue");
```

I don´t know why it was working with a .Net Framework WebApi, but is not working with a .Net Core WebApi.

I could resolve using the below code:

```
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(method, Method.POST);

request.AddJsonBody(objBody);
```

With the new method, the RestSharp is responsible to serialize my object.

It's working right now.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, but server used SSO identify 4, it is not support input json. Could you have any other solution?

Comment: Hi Tony.
Some days ago I had a problem similar to yours when I updated my RestSharp version from 106.4.2 to 106.5.4.

I did the downgrade of the version (to 106.4.2) and the calls returned to work again.

What version are you using?